# how to count possible planar bipartitions?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, integer-partitions

i want to find out what small fraction of a solution space a metaheuristic search is actually covering.

this case comes down to the number of possible bipartitions for a non-bipartite, undirected planar graph (it's a political map). the resulting two subgraphs don't need to get exactly half the vertices: any bipartition into two connected subgraphs is a valid solution and i have an objective function to value them.

bipartition is NP-Hard and lots of algorithms and heuristics have been designed to find optimal cases faster. (for example, liption & tarjan showed in the 1970s how to do a particular planar tripartition in linear time.) that's great, but i haven't found any description of the complexity of exhaustively enumerating all bipartition possibilities.

i believe that a bipartition along a planar separator, made of edge cuts which cross the graph, is also exactly a circuit in the graph's dual, at the outer face. if i could count the number of possible circuits at that vertex, i'd know how many ways the graph could be bipartitioned.

does this avenue seem promising? how would the rest of you tackle this question?

Comment: It seems to me that the number of ways a graph can be bipartitioned is $2^{|V|-1}$ unless you add some constraints. Have I missed a constraint?

Comment: thanks Peter. that looks like the formula for a set partition, but these subgraphs have to stay connected. consider two four-node graphs, one fully connected, and one that's just three lines; i count twice as many ways to bipartition the former. therefore, i know the answer to this question will involve the edges, possibly work with the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix, which seems like a popular approach to such problems.

Comment: Ah. At present the question says "*any bipartition at all is a valid solution*", so if you really want each half of the partition to be connected you should edit the text to clarify that.

Comment: i think the general graph bisection problem includes this assumption, and i edited the question to reflect the constraint.